# Replace partial with another rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my index page I have one partial:

Index-Site:

```
<div id="chapter_list">
<%= render 'icd1' %>
</div>
```

This partial _icd1 should have links to another partial _icd2.

Actually _icd1 links to a normal site:

```
<% @icd1.each do |f| %>
<%= link_to "#{f.von} - #{f.bis}  #{f.bezeichnung}", icd_show_path(f), remote: true  %>
<% end %>
```

So my **first question**is how can i link to a partial _icd2 with the param "f"?

And next i would like that when a user clicks in the partial _icd1 on the link to _icd2, the partial _icd1 disappears and the partial _icd2 is rendered instead:

So that the index-Site looks like:

```
<div id="chapter_list">
<%= render 'icd2' %>
</div>
```

As you can see in my second code snippet my links already respond with ajax. But i have no clue how i can remove the _icd1 partial and display the partial icd2 instead, with js!! So that my icd2.js.erb file actually looks like this:

```
$('#chapter_list').fadeOut();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#chapter_list').html("<%= j render('icd2') %>");
```