# How do I replace one partial with another in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partials

I have a form partial that I want to replace with an isbn_lookup_result partial. How do I make an ajax request to replace the result I am given by my GET request on my page? I have looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242671/replace-partial-with-another-rails), but it does not seem to be what I am looking for.

Here is the relevant code:

_form.html.erb (in views > listings)

```
    <%= render "shared/errors", obj: @listing %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= form_for(@listing, :html => {class: "form-horizontal" , role: "form"}, method: :get) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :isbn, "ISBN" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :isbn, id: "auto-isbn", class: "form-control" , placeholder: "ISBN (10 or 13 digits)", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :title %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :title , class: "form-control" , placeholder: "Title of book", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :condition %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :condition , class: "form-control" , placeholder: "Book condition", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label "Department(s)" %>
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name,{:"data-style" => "form-control", :"data-size" => "5"}, {class: "selectpicker", title: "Choose Department(s)", multiple: true}) %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :price %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :price , class: "form-control" , placeholder: "Price (in $USD)", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= f.label :description  %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= f.text_area :description , rows:8, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Description", autofocus: true %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
          <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
        </div>
    </div>
  <%end%>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
  <%= link_to "Cancel request and return to listings page", listings_path %>
</div>
```

_isbn_lookup_result (in views > listings)

```
<%= form_for(@listing, :html => {class: "form-horizontal" , role: "form"}, method: :get) do |f| %>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :isbn, "ISBN" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :isbn, id: "auto-isbn", class: "form-control" , placeholder: "ISBN (10 or 13 digits)", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :title %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
                <%= f.text_field :title , class: "form-control" , placeholder: "Title of book", autofocus: true, id: "isbn-lookup-results-container" do %><%= @isbn_lookup_result[:title] %><% end %>

      </div>
    </div>
    ...
    <% end %>
```

Current method for ISBN lookup that returns info about book in listing.rb file

```
def self.isbn_lookup(val)
request = Vacuum.new('US')
request.configure(
aws_access_key_id: 'access_key_here',
aws_secret_access_key: 'secret_access_key_here',
associate_tag: 'associate_tag_here'
)
response = request.item_lookup(
  query: {
    'ItemId' => val,
    'SearchIndex' => 'Books',
    'IdType' => 'ISBN'
  },
  persistent: true
)
fr = response.to_h #returns complete hash
author = fr.dig("ItemLookupResponse","Items","Item","ItemAttributes","Author")
title = fr.dig("ItemLookupResponse","Items","Item","ItemAttributes","Title")
manufacturer = fr.dig("ItemLookupResponse","Items","Item","ItemAttributes","Manufacturer")
url = fr.dig("ItemLookupResponse","Items","Item","ItemLinks","ItemLink",6,"URL")
return {title: title, author: author, manufacturer: manufacturer, url: url}
  end
```

Lookup action in listings_controller.rb

```
  def lookup
    @isbn_lookup_result = Listing.isbn_lookup(params[:isbn])
    render partial: 'isbn_lookup_result'
  end
```

Attempt at AJAX request isbn_lookup.js file (big shoutout to jvillian for helping me get this far)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  @TIMEOUT = null

  $(document).on('keyup','input #auto-isbn',function() {
    clearTimeout(@TIMEOUT)
    @TIMEOUT = setTimeout(function(){
      var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
        url: "listings/lookup",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {isbn: $('input#auto-isbn').val()}
      });
      ajaxResponse.success(function(data){
        $('#isbn-lookup-results-container').html(data)
      });
      //ajaxResponse.error(function(data){
        // Make an error div or something show up
      //});
    }, 500);
  });

});
```

Comment: Hi again. Could you update your question with the entire `_form.html.erb`? I'm trying to get a better feel for what that form actually does. From the bit you've posted, it looks like a user can do a lookup either by ISBN or title, is that correct?

Comment: Just added the rest of the _form.html.erb code jvillian. Still having trouble making the logical leap from getting the result and then actually making that result display (changing from the form partial to the isbn_lookup_result partial).

Comment: Also, aren't variables in Javascript normally not declared with the @ sign? Should I replace `@TIMEOUT` with `var timeout = null` and then just use `timeout` instead of `@TIMEOUT`?

Comment: Continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/154724/how-do-i-replace-one-partial-with-another-in-rails?tab=general)?

Comment: Click on the link in my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$('#isbn-lookup-results-container').html(data)
```

nothing is going to happen because you don't have a `div` with `id="isbn-lookup-results-container"`. So, you may want to do something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="isbn-lookup-results-container" class="col-md-12">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

In your forms, you do `autofocus: true` many times. Only do it once on the field you want to be autofocused when the form loads.

I think I would make the end of `self.isbn_lookup` include the `isbn`, something like:

```
return {title: title, author: author, manufacturer: manufacturer, url: url, isbn: val}
```

Your `_isbn_lookup_result.html.erb` looks to be identical to the form in `_form.html.erb`. Don't you want to do something with the results of `isbn_lookup`? Maybe something like:

```
<%= form_for(@listing, :html => {class: "form-horizontal" , role: "form"}, method: :get) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :isbn, "ISBN" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_field :isbn, id: "auto-isbn", class: "form-control" , placeholder: "ISBN (10 or 13 digits)", value: @isbn_lookup_result[:isbn] %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
      <%= f.label :title %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <%= f.text_field :title , class: "form-control" , placeholder: "Title of book", value: @isbn_lookup_result[:title], autofocus: true %>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
<%end%>
```

So that the values for `isbn` and `title` are shown in the new form.

You don't use `author`, `manufacturer`, or `url` anywhere. Is that what you intend? Seems strange to load those into your `hash` if you're not going to use them.

Comment: I decided to add `author`, `manufacturer`, and `url` so that I can use them later if I want. However, I am still having some difficulty with this. It seems like my ajax isn't recognizing when I am done typing. I have changed my code to add the div with id `isbn-lookup-results`